# Tkinter images glitch when placed in different thread

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-multithreading

So i'm trying to make a gui and make images appear on the gui, but when I place an image onto the gui it starts flashing depending on where I drag the gui on my computer...

Heres code that causes this effect:

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import *
root = Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)

image1 = PhotoImage(file="GUI.png")
w = image1.width()
h = image1.height()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))

panel1 = Label(root, image=image1)
panel1.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
def PlaceImage():
    global panel1
    test = PhotoImage(file="test.png")
    label = Label(panel1, image=test)
    label.image = test
    label.place(x=0, y=0)
def thethread():
    PlaceImage()

thread = Thread(target=thethread)
thread.start()
root.mainloop()
```

The gui comes out just fine, but the image I place is what is glitchy. If anyone knows why this is and how to fix it that would be very helpful!

Comment: "label" should not exist after the function exits.  Comment the 3 lines dealing with "label = Label", etc. in the fundtion and see if that eliminates the problem.  GUI programming is best done with classes which handle these problems.

Comment: Except label is placed() to it does remain after the function. Also, a png file is handled by Pillow (fork of PIL), not PhotoImage although I have seen rumors that it will be changed so Tkinter handles pngs but don't know if that has happened so to be on the safe side, use PIL.

Comment: Tkinter is putting the png's on the gui, so I dont think that is the issue. Also I dont really understand what you mean by "Comment the 3 lines dealing with "label = Label", etc" so maybe if you could post an example on how to fix the issue that would be better

Comment: I have no problem when I run on Linux so problem can depend on system. But I see 3 other problems - 1. `tkinter` is not thread-safe so it may not work when you use it in thread, 2. standard `tkinter` can read/display only GIF images, to work with other format you need `pillow/PIL` module, 3. there is bug with PhotoImage and with Garbage Collector which removes image from memory when it is assigned to local variable (created in function). See **Note:** on page [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Do this to see if this eliminates the problem or if it is somewhere else.i.e. we have to know where the problem is before we can solve it. If this does solve the problem then try PIL imstead of PhotoImage next. *I have no problem when I run on Linux*  That may also be because you run a newer version of Tkinter than the OP is running and it incorporates PIL into Tktinter where as the OP's does not.

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import *
root = Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)

image1 = PhotoImage(file="GUI.png")
w = image1.width()
h = image1.height()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))

panel1 = Label(root, image=image1)
panel1.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
def PlaceImage():
    global panel1
    ##test = PhotoImage(file="test.png")
    ##label = Label(panel1, image=test)
    ##abel.image = test
    ##label.place(x=0, y=0)
def thethread():
    PlaceImage()

thread = Thread(target=thethread)
thread.start()
root.mainloop()
```